# vf pagination page can't offset the data

Tags: pagination, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

https://github.com/RuRu1229/paging-page

this is my page&apexCode

I want to do when I press the button,I can dispaly the (next/previous) five value In the screen.
Now I have six value,but when I press the button.
Although ,My page is rerender ,My value is only display the originally five value.
After testing,I found the offsum will not renew.
But I don't Know how can I change My code to achieve the Purpose.
Can someBody help me?

I try to

```
 pageRef.getParameters().put('Offset', String.valueOf(offNum)); //
```

and hive off my soql to a founction

Answer (score 0):

You set the offset to be passed via URL but you never seem to read it? Your `bondOfferingService` method reads the ID - why not other params?

Have you seen the "proper" way to do pagination? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_custom_list_controller.htm

And don't call your pages/classes "test", it can lead to amusing compilation errors because it'd clash with built-in System.Test class.